LBFGS-B initial gradients too high?
I'm optimizing a geometrical shape for electromagnetic performance. The shape is constrained with bounds, say between 0.2 and 0.8, whereas the parameters are all between 0.2 and 0.8.
I am interested in knowing the initial conditions effect on the convergence. But as soon as I run LBFGS, it immediately shoots everything to the bounds because the gradient is so high.
How should I deal with this?
FYI, the code looks something like this:
the optimizer is scipy minimize. the fom and the jacobian function are given as inputs, alongside the pgtol and iterations.
No Hessian is given by default. The Jacobian and FOM are recovered through a simulation in electromagnetics which returns a FOM for forward and gradient for backward pass.

You probably want to use a line search with BFGS if you don't have a good initial guess for the BFGS-Hessian (or at least its diagonal).

Can you provide some more information about the optimizer and its behavior? Some information that may be helpful would be whether this is an implementation from an existing package (it likely uses a good line search by default if so), whether it is showing convergence in exactly one iteration or if it takes multiple, and whether/how much the function value decreases from the initial guess. It may be the case that the solver is working as intended but the constraints are very tight and some hyperparameter tuning in the line search may fix this

Thank you! I added some more information.
Namely, no Hessian is provided by default. Only a FOM and Jacobian function is provided. Both simply do an electromagnetic simulation and recover gradients (this works fine I've verified.) Its just the gradients are quite high and the first update to parameters immediately moves all parameters to bounds.
By the way, I am using scipy minimize. We expect (almost certainly) that this is a HIGHLY CONCONVEX solution space.

@whpowell96 I would say that it is working yes. It immediately bounces to the bounds but then adjusts and moves towards a local minima. My problem is that my problem space is highly nonconvex so I'd like to test for different initial conditions. But if after one iteration its essentially starting from the bounds, I worry that I cannot properly test for nonconvexity.

@WolfgangBangerth I am using scipy minimize. do you think it would have a line search already? It always, and I mean ALWAYS, seems to immediately jump to the bounds.

By the way, it doesnt jump to the bounds in the first ITERATION with scipy minimize. It jumps to it after the first time it calls the jacobian, whcih is not the same as the first iteration. I am confused about the difference between iteration and each time it calls the fom and jacobian. Is it doing a line search perhaps when it jumps to the bounds? Do the initial conditions still matter then? I am just not sure how LBFGSB works I guess.

The initial Hessian is the identity matrix for BFGS. SciPy calls the gradient routine every BFGS iteration to generate a search direction and it then calls the objective function multiple times to perform a line search in this direction. I don't know if it is possible to get line search diagnostic information within scipy, but it may be the case that the gradients being so large is causing the entire line search to lie outside the constraint set. Try increasing the maxls argument in the LBFGS method and see if that helps

It sounds like the full step takes you to the bounds, but a few line-search iterations identify a promising step. Then you do end up at a local minimum. So everything's fine.

@CharlieVanaret Can you explain the line search to me? Whats weird is that in each iteration, it will jump to the bounds, and then UPDATE the parameters, and carry on from there? I would have thought it would jump to the bounds, then do a different line search, then a different one until it has a promising step.

I think I'm still not quite sure what the problem is. Does the method actually find the minimum?

At the current point $x_k$, we solve the subproblem (a QP with BFGS Hessian approximation), which produces a direction (a vector) $d_k$. We'd like to generate the next point $x_k + \alpha d_k$, where $\alpha \in (0, 1]$ is the step length. Ideally, we'd like to take $\alpha = 1$ (because we make large moves) but it may well be that the corresponding trial iterate ($x_k + d_k$) is bad. The line search iteratively decreases $\alpha$ starting from $\alpha = 1$ until the trial iterate $x_k + \alpha d_k$ is "good enough" (it sufficiently decreases the objective and/or the constraint violation).
